# Can't connect to Ubuntu 20.04 Hotspot (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, hotspot, ubuntu-20.04

So recently I put Ubuntu on my old laptop to use as a hotspot and everything worked fine. I managed to connect it to my phone with no problem however when trying it out on my pc (windows 10) it can't connect. I've tried restarting both pc with no success. Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Edit: I should probably add that when trying to connect to another network like my phone's hotspot it manages to connect

Comment: Try to disable firewalls?

Comment: I should probably add that when trying to connect to another network like my phone's hotspot it manages to connect